# Python - Как остановить итерацию цикла for через метод класса __next__?

Tags: python, for

Как создать итерируемый объект, подстраиваемый под цикл for.
Вся проблема в том, что при достижения крайнего элемента, при следующей итерации возникает исключение:

```
    return self.listing[self.key]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Когда хотелось бы, чтобы не возникало ошибок, и цикл заканчивал выполнение как только все элементы будут перебраны.

Мой код:

```
class iteration:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, values):
        # итерируемый объект
        self.values = values
        # начальный индекс с запасом
        self.index = -1
        # количество элементов (по индексу)
        self.len_index = len(values) - 1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.index += 1
        return self.values[self.index]


for i in iteration(['Tom', 'Tim', 'Mark', 'May']):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 4):

вместо `__next__` лучше реализовать `__iter__`

```
    def __iter__(self):
        for el in self.values:
            yield el
```

либо так:

```
    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.values
```

В данном случае переменные `self.index` и `self.len_index` не нужны

Answer (score 3):

Для этого можно использовать исключение `StopIteration`:

```
def __next__(self):
    self.index += 1
    if self.index >= len(self.values):
        raise StopIteration
    return self.values[self.index]
```